# Grub resetting ruint my windows hard disk partitons

Tags: partitioning, grub

I wanted to run memtest86, but I could not find it in grub, so I followed this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu
After I run in I later noticed that all my windows partitions are gone. I can't access to them and I can't see them in my computer. I can see them windows partion tools. Also I can't see them in ubuntu.

Pleas help. Did I just lost everything like that?

Edit: Here is the partitions:
[image]

In drive 2, there should be more partitions

Comment: We don't know what you did nor what the situation looks like, except for a very vague description. Please add all the details you have, including partitioning screenshots. Otherwise we can't help you. Use the [edit] button.